# JQuery Carousel - IF ELSE statment to display as first( "active") a hyperlinked image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a JQuery carousel with four images stored in a file called carousel.php. I also have a gallery.php file where are the four images in  a list as hyperlinks. When I click on them I get their "id"

```
<li><a href='carousel.php?id=1'><img src=1.jpg'></a></li>
<li><a href='carousel.php?id=2'><img src=2.jpg'></a></li>
<li><a href='carousel.php?id=3'><img src=3.jpg'></a></li>
<li><a href='carousel.php?id=4'><img src=4.jpg'></a></li>
```

at the gallery.php through $id=$_GET['id'] and then I create a javascript variable of this id called $imgvar.

```
var $imgvar = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
```

So, I want the carousel to display first the image which was clicked by the user and then continue the normal order.
(e.g. if I click 3.jpg, the carousel starts displaying 3.jpg and then I click the "right navigation arrow" goes to 4.jpg or if I click the "left navigation arrow" goes to 2.jpg etc).

I guess I need a IF else statments to compare the id with each image and make "active" the one which was hyperlinked, but I can't find the right way.
Anybody who might help?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could just simply use the [scroll](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#scroll) method to scroll to the item via index directly after initialization …

Comment: You are right. I did it with scroll method via jcarousel and php. It simply works. Thank you.

Comment: OK, added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just simply use the [scroll](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#scroll) method to scroll to the item via index directly after initialization.

Take the number of the item from your GET parameter, and output the JavaScript code to call the `scroll` method with that number. (If you are passing numbers from 1 to x, you will have to decrement it by one, because `scroll` uses the zero-based item index.)